# Difference between storage and operating temperatures

Tags: networking, hardware

What is the difference between Operating temperatue & storage temperature of switch C3560E ?

Answer (score 6):

- *Operating temperature*: The range where you can safely *operate* this device.
- *Storage temperature*: The range where you can safely *store* the device for longer periods of time *when powered off*.